# Python: How to use write/export to file in a different function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, io, output

I'm trying to write a export to file function in Python. Here's a snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def function_1(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        ip = packet[i]
        mac = mac[i]
        print '{}, {}'.format(ip, mac)

def export()
    f=open("data.txt", "w")
    f.write() #f.write(function_1(x))??
    f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    function_1(10)
    export()
```

I can do write to a file by putting it in the same function as function_1, but how would I do it in another function? Do I need to return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, f.write needs a string for input.  The easiest way is to create the string directly in your function and return it:

```
def function_1(x):
    ret_val = ""
    for i in range(len(x)):
        ip = packet[i]
        mac = mac[i]
        ret_val += '{}, {}\n'.format(ip, mac)
    return ret_val
```